# printing the binary representation of signed ints

Tags: c++, c, binary

I need a function to print the binary representation of of a signed int, I have the  following which works on both negative and positive integers, it works because the unsigned value of `1 << 31 = 2147483648`, is this a valid way to do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printBinary(int n) {

    for (unsigned i = 1 << 31; i > 0; i = i >> 1) {
        if (i & n) {
            printf("1");
        } else {
            printf("0");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {

    printBinary(2147483647); // 01111111111111111111111111111111
    printBinary(-2147483647); // 10000000000000000000000000000001
    printBinary(-2147483648); // 10000000000000000000000000000000
    printBinary(2147483648); // can't be represented, will produce wrong results
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::bitset::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is the easiest way IMHO.

Comment: Because it is greater than a signed int...

Comment: You might be happier having `printBinary` take `unsigned int` as a parameter. Signed integers convert to unsigned in a predictable manner; the converse is not true (signed integer overflow exhibits undefined behavior).

Comment: yes it prints wrong results, I'll change it

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Converting an unsigned integer to an signed one is not UB but at most implementation defined. See [conv.integral]/3.

Comment: @Columbo Not "clearly defined", but "implementation-defined": "**4.7/3** If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined." I was incorrect in claiming UB (though "implementation-defined" is only marginally better).

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

It works correctly with signed ints.

If the compiler complains that it is deprecated use this function:
_itoa_s

small example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char bin[33];
    _itoa_s(-5456,bin,2);
    printf("%s",bin);
    return 0;
}
```